# How do i make a counter that works for me on django Models

Tags: python, django, count, model

i have a question. i am trying to make some counter for my models. i have model- personeel and kwalification. i want to make a couter that counts how mutch personeel got the same kwalification like if 2 personeel got ehbo then it counts 2.

```
def kwalificatietotaal(request):
    count = Kwalificaties.objects.annotate(ehbo=Count('wel'))
    teller = 0
    if count == count:
        teller += 1

        print(count)

    return render(request, 'accounts/kwalificatieTotaal.html')


class Kwalificaties (models.Model):
    objects = None
    TREIN_SOORTEN = (
        ('Traxx', 'Traxx'),
        ('Intercity Direct', 'Intercity Direct'),
        ('Intercity Nieuwe Generatie', 'Intercity Nieuwe Generatie'),
        ('Intercity Rijthuig', 'Intercity Rijthuig')
    )
    E_H_B_O = (
        ('Wel', 'Wel'),
        ('Niet', 'Niet'),
    )
    EXTRA_KENNIS = (
        ('Bio werkzaamheden', 'Bio werkzaamheden'),
        ('Kuil werkzaamheden', 'Kuil werkzaamheden'),
        ('Aardwind werkzaamheden', 'Aardwind werkzaamheden'),
        ('Airco Monteur', 'Airco Monteur'),
        ('Z.Z-Deuren Monteur', 'Z.Z-Deuren Monteur'),
        ('Vooropnamen Elektrisch', 'Vooropnamen Elektrisch'),
        ('Rijbevoegd Monteur', 'Rijbevoegd Monteur'),
        ('MTC', 'MTC'),
        ('EBKC', 'EBKC'),
        ('Heftruck kwalificatie', 'Heftruck kwalificatie'),
        ('Hoogwerker kwalificatie', 'Hoogwerker kwalificatie')

    )
    naam = models.ForeignKey(Personeel, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    treinen = MultiSelectField(max_length=200, choices=TREIN_SOORTEN)
    ehbo = MultiSelectField(max_length=200, choices=E_H_B_O)
    extra = MultiSelectField(max_length=200, choices=EXTRA_KENNIS)
```

Comment: `if count == count:` no idea what are you doing here, but this results in tautology (always true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kwalificaties.objects.filter(ehbo="wel").count()`

maybe?